# How to run Xunit test from command line with parameters

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, xunit

Currently i am running my tests on visual studio, where I pass my command line argument with the dll.

Now to setup with CI/CD pipeline, I need to pass the parameter, also it won't be good approach to directly pass the DLL.

PS : These are not standard xunit test, its just we are using xunit to run the UI test. So can't use the Test explorer

Any suggestions. Thanks in anticipation
[image]

Comment: Are you starting the test via the VS debugger? Can you start it from the TestExplorer window?

Comment: @cph I have to figure out a way to run this in pipeline using cmd, Also there are not standard xunit test. I am just using Xunit to call my UI test javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, you could use a `.runsettings` file for this. These files enabled you to configure tests, but also enabled you to use your own parameters through [`TestRunParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#testrunparameters). With xUnit, this is not a possibility.

Running your xUnit tests in your CI/CD pipeline would be simplest by running [`dotnet test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) from the command line.

For xUnit, the standard to pass something like command line parameters is to use Environment Variables, as seen in this [GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1908).